# Extension Methods needing a Unity Resolve

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a few extension methods that are fairly core to my app.  I use them to route all calls to my OData service through a central Exception Handler.  It looks like this:

```
var results = Entites.Customers.Where(x=>x.IsActive).Invoke();
```

The `Invoke()` is my extension method, and it all works great!

But when I get an exception, I would like to log it.

The problem I finding is that my `ILogger` cannot be resolved inside a `static` class (the class **must** be static for it to have extension methods.)

**Is there any way to resolve a unity managed interface inside of a `static` Class?**  Or is the Dependency Injection pattern just not able to cope with this C# feature?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Or better yet, just `Where(x => x.IsActive)`

Comment: There is a simple solution: Don't use extension methods. Once that `Invoke` method needs dependencies of its own, it gets a service of its own and you will have to inject it just like you inject all your other services. You can't use that convenient extension method syntax anymore. Live with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to just not have any implementation in the static class.  Create a non-static class that contains the implementation of the method (not as an extension method) then have the extension method do nothing besides call the non-extension implementation.

After doing that the implementation is no longer in a static class.

```
public static class MyExtension
{
    public static void Invoke<T>(this IQueryable<T> query) 
    {
        MyExtensionImplementation.Invoke(query);
    }
}

internal class MyExtensionImplementation
{
    public static void Invoke<T>(IQueryable<T> query) 
    {
        //actual work
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if this approach would really resolve a problem. What benefits does this approach provide? How are you going to inject ILogger inside an extension method?

Comment: @Warlock Yes, it resolves the problem, the benefit is that the implementation is not within a static class, what was specifically what the OP said was the problem.  The idea is not to inject a logger, the idea is for the class to have it's own, but that can't be done if it's static.

Comment: Actually you delegate one static method implementation to another. Could you please provide little bit more code in the class "MyExtensionImplementation" to make it more understandable for me :) or provide links on external resources? I'm really interested in this solution. Thanks

Comment: @Warlock The method is static, but the class is not, that's the key point.  This solves the problem that the OP has in entirety, if you are in a different situation such that this doesn't solve your problem then perhaps you should post a new question with *your* problem.

Comment: Servy, the class is non-static, so you can't use members of this class in a static method. So, how are you going to use MyExtensionImplementation and where is an ILogger?

Comment: @Warlock I already showed you how the class is used, and the OP didn't ask how the logger should be used within the class; he just said that he wanted a non-static class, so that's what I gave him.  If he's curious how to proceed he can ask for clarification, but given that he's accepted the answer and not discussed it further it would appear that this is sufficient for him to solve the remainder of the problem himself.  Again, if there's something that you want that is beyond the scope of this question, ask one of your own.

Comment: You can't use ILogger in MyExtension class, because Invoke method is static. This answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A bad news - there is no way to do this, a good news - you don't need to log exceptions inside your extension methods. Just let an exception to be throwen outside the static class and handle it in a proper way.

```
IResult results;
try
{
  results = Entites.Customers.Where(x=>x.IsActive).Invoke();
}
catch(YourOwnException ex)
{
  Log(ex, "The Business logic error.");
}
catch(ArgumentException ex)
{
  Log(ex, "Invalid arguments.")
}
...
catch(Exception ex)
{
  Log(ex, "Unknown error.");
}
```

**EDIT:**

> Most of them are communications related and would be handled in the
>   extension method. Just a few that are business related will be
>   rethrown.

If exceptions are "communications related" or 3-rd party, maybe you don't need to log them. In this case I would create a `TryInvoke()` method without logging, which returns `TRUE` for a success operation and has an `OUT` parameter. If you want to log them you should inject `ILogger` inside your `Invoke()` method.

```
if(Entites.Customers.Where(x=>x.IsActive).TryInvoke(out results))
{
  // Success
}
```

Comment: +1, only log exceptions when they are handled, not when they are thrown.

Comment: Most of them are communications related and would be handled in the extension method.  Just a few that are business related will be rethrown.